# Scala - Combining Try, Option, Or, Good, ErrorMessage

Tags: scala, scalactic

I have two methods that are used to create Currency enums from Strings. The enum Currency is a Java enum.

Their signatures are:

```
def sCurrency: Option[Currency] Or One[ErrorMessage] =  ???
def cCurrency: Currency Or One[ErrorMessage] = ???
```

Try as I might I can't seem to get the Try / Recover with and type parameters correct for all situations. I've hacked implementations together to only handle the Good -

```
def cCurrency: Currency Or One[ErrorMessage] =     
    Good(String2Currency(currencyString))

def sCurrency: Option[Currency] Or One[ErrorMessage] = 
    Good(currencyString map (String2Currency(_)))

implicit def String2Currency(v: String): Currency = Currency.valueOf(v.toUpperCase)
```

I struggled to find an article that covers the complexity of mixing Try, One, Options, Or and recoverWith, so my question is twofold - How should I implement these methods, and can anyone explain / link an article on what is actually going here and how it works?

I can't change the return types of either method.

Comment: May I know what's `Or, Good, ErrorMessage`?

Comment: Also, what is `One` and `StringToCurrency`?

Comment: Or, Good, One etc are part of Scalactic - http://www.scalactic.org/
ErrorMessage is a Scalactic type alias for String. 
String2Currency is an implicit listed as the last line of code above.